# MBCalendar kit framework how to add in my project

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, calendar, mbcalendarkit

I used `MBCalendar` kit framework. and successfully added in my project, but problem is that months and dates cant show simulator. only one top bar show in this weeks and year show. I attached my output snap shot please find this and show bellow. I want to successfully calendar show in UI. how it possible please help.

```
#import "ViewController.h"
#import "CalendarKit/CalendarKit.h"

@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
  [super viewDidLoad];

  CKCalendarView *calendar = [CKCalendarView new];

  [calendar setDelegate:self];
  [calendar setDataSource:self];

  [[self view] addSubview:calendar];

}
```

[image: Look like this my output]

Comment: you are using MBCalendar or CKCalendarVIew?

Comment: https://github.com/jaykz52/CKCalendar    & https://www.cocoacontrols.com/controls/ckcalendar

Comment: @BhadreshKathiriya I used MBCalendar KIt https://github.com/MosheBerman/MBCalendarKit

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Follow my step:

Step 1: remove you are implement all related to MBCalendar.

Step 2: include CKDemoViewController.h & CKDemoViewController.m file in your project.

Step 3: set your view design class to CKDemoViewController.

check some file: https://github.com/BhadreshKathiriya/MBCalendar

```
 - (IBAction)btnClick:(id)sender {
    [self presentViewController:[[CKDemoViewController alloc] init] animated:YES completion:nil];
    //Or
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:[[CKDemoViewController alloc] init] animated:YES];
 }
```

Comment: Thank you. calendar are show proper. and one more main problem faced, How to add events, web service through get date .

Comment: how to add calendar another screen. i want to button click after move to another page then open calendar screen. so how it possible. please help

Comment: It's possible to anther screen.

Comment: - (IBAction)btnClick:(id)sender {
    [self presentViewController:[[CKDemoViewController alloc] init] animated:YES completion:nil];   
or
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:[[CKDemoViewController alloc] init] animated:YES];
}

Comment: It's also possible to web service through get date but before view call web service after calendar view controller page call or web service calendar view controller call get response data then you are reload current view controller means call [self viewDidLoad] or [self viewWillAppear:Yes] or set response data method below Calendar event call.

Comment: I added btnclick action but some error show bellow :- no known class method for selector 'alloc'

Comment: who is use storyboard or xib?

Comment: I used a storyboard

Comment: @Bhadersh Kathiriya I used a storyboard. please help

Comment: @BhadreshKathiriya i am new to iOS development and i am using swift 2.3, in my case i don't want to user view controller instead i want to add calendar view as subview....can you please guide me